# Resurrection of Richard Strauss

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A new art form has captured the world's attention: the reconstruction of past personalities based on their works and historical records. When the Richard Strauss, composer of such works as Also Sprach Zarathustra [the theme music at the beginning of "2001: A Space Odyssey"!] is resurrected, he undergoes a difficult period of adjustment. Who is he, after all, and what use should he make of this new life? Eventually he gets down to work, and feverishly composes a new symphony that he is sure will be his best. The world is fascinated and it's a full house at the premiere. But as Strauss conducts his symphony, he is struck by its banality. He realizes that he has composed nothing truly new, but has combined themes and ideas from his older works. The applause, however, is deafening. As Strauss turns to face the audience, he realizes that the applause is not for him, but for the artist who reconstructed him.

I am not at all sure of the date of this short story, which I read in English in an anthology. It could date from the 70s or as late as the 00s.

Comment: There's a reincarnation of Richard Strauss here... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167097/98028 "A work of Art", James Blish. Is that it? Edit: yeah, that's got to be it: _"There was nothing new about the music. It was the old Strauss all over again - but weaker, more dilute than ever."_

Comment: Yes indeed. Although the story was first published in 1956, I probably read it during the 1980s, when a lot of Blish stories were revived in collections. This one was reprinted in "Galactic Cluster."
Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Work_of_Art