# 80s novel, a time traveler rescues a dying classical composer and brings him to future to start composing on modern instruments

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, music

I am trying to recall the title of a novel. It is probably from the 80s (maybe as early as 70s,) in English, USA paperback.

I am pretty sure the cover had a piano keyboard wrapped around a person so he could easily play it. Like 360, or maybe in infinity shape. Not straight, it was curved.

Similar to this:

[image]

The MC gets hold of a time machine. I am not sure if he nvented it, inherited it, stole it, or found it.

I *think* he installed it in his van.

Main plot point: He went back in time and rescued a dying classical musician. Not Bach or Beethoven, but someone a little less well known. (Shubert or Liszt or someone like that.) He was dying of an STD and only had a few days(?) to live, before the MC 'rescued' him, brought him back to the future and cured it. The MC gave him modern instruments/equipment and let him compose. The MC *might* have then passed the composer's new work off as his own.

I have vague recollections of a title something like "The xxxxxxx Time Machine" but my GoogleFoo is poor and I am not finding anything.

Comment: Wow, that's a *whole lot* like  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167097/28516

Comment: Is it possible you're misremembering the short [Gianni](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58610) by Silverberg? Gianni Pergolesi is brought forward in time using a _time scoop_ and he becomes a pop musician before dying of a drug overdose.

Comment: Nope. This was a book. NOT the short story. When I wrote the question, that question popped up as similar, and I read it. But it was NOT the same story I remember. I vividly remember the cover with the keyboard wrapping around the player.

Comment: There was one from _Omni_ involving Mozart.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds like *[Mixed Doubles](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?19056)*, a novel from 1989 by Daniel da Cruz.

The plot deals with a music student called Justin Pope, who inherits a time machine, and uses it to bring Schubert to the present day. The cover blurb from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2031197.Mixed_Doubles) summarises the plot as:

> A university student uses a time machine to kidnap Schubert from his
> deathbed. He brings the master to the present and cures him, then
> exploits his talents to advance his own career.

The cover indeed shows a piano keyboard wrapped around the player.

[image: Cover of "Mixed Doubles", showing a piano keyboard wrapped around the player.]

Comment: Heh.  I would not have read this because after *The Ayes of Texas* I decided I was done with da Cruz. :D

Comment: Yes, this is the book!. Hmm, Hey I enjoyed *The Ayes of Texas* when it came out. :p