# 60s or 70s science fiction short stories on fine arts

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book, art

I’m looking for a 1960s-70s science fiction short story anthology on fine arts. I only remember the summary of 2 of the stories.

One was of composer who wrote commercial music by hand while most wrote using AI so they could “compose” music faster and he was having trouble getting his music sold.

Another was of a community in which a psychologically troubled person lived and he did not know that the people around him were all actors creating an environment to help “cure” him

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167097/short-sci-fi-story-involving-revival-of-a-classical-composer?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the collection [New Dreams This Morning.](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?23732)
"A Science Fiction Anthology about the Future of the Arts." as [the cover](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/b/b4/NWDRRNNG4E1966.jpg) describes it.

The first story sounds like *A Work Of Art*, by James Blish.

It has been discussed on the forum a few times.

[Short sci-fi story involving revival of a classical composer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167097/short-sci-fi-story-involving-revival-of-a-classical-composer)

The second story sounds like [Time Out Of Joint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Out_of_Joint), which is a novel, and isn't in the anthology. Perhaps you are conflating.