# Can anybody help me find a short story from the 70s about a musical prodigy chosen from birth?

Tags: story-identification

I read a story in the 70s about a child that was predicted to be a musical genius and left alone with musical instruments and absolutely no outside musical influences. He eventually was exposed in some way to outside music and forbidden to play again.

Comment: Sounds like ["Unaccompanied Sonata"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40836) by Orson Scott Card, which was previously identified as the answer to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37881/name-of-short-sci-fi-story-involving-a-musician-who-is-punished-for-listening-to). The story was in the March 1979 *Omni* which is available in the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/omni-magazine-1979-03).

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I suspect that gilstrap's comment of acceptance got deleted at some point, making user14111 sound rather self-congratulatory. :-P