# Story where making music illegal

Tags: story-identification

Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of details on this story; I can't even recall *when* I read it - except that it was almost certainly over 30 years ago. It may have been a story in an anthology, but I won't swear to that; I have the impression that it may actually have been novella-length.

The basic plot element was that it was illegal to create music in the social context of the story, and the protagonist did so. The only real detail from the story that I recall is a scene where they stopped him from singing by placing a device against his throat that disabled his larynx, and later had to stop him from playing by (painlessly) amputating his fingers.

Comment: It sounds a bit like the plot to Rush' s album 2112, but that is not the right media. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2112_(album)

Comment: I've not listened to the album; that's not my preferred musical style. Perhaps this story, whatever it turns out to be, was their inspiration?

Comment: @Jontia That was what I thought as I read the question, too, but it also sounds like something we might have seen from Kurt Vonnegutt Jr. (similar theme and setting to "Harrison Bergeron").

Comment: Definitely not H.B.; the deliberate handicapping for political correctness reasons was absolutely not part of the cultural background in the story. Admittedly, though, the plot I remember does sound like it might be Vonnegut.

Comment: Like the same story ("Unaccompanied Sonata") as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37881/name-of-short-sci-fi-story-involving-a-musician-who-is-punished-for-listening-to and links therein.

Comment: Incidentally, the music of Afro-Brazilian slaves *was* made illegal (along with dance and capoeira) in Brazil in periods during and following slavery.

Comment: @Lexible: It's one of those hazy things where it started out with slavery, then became about the criminal element using Capoeira in street fights that sometimes got bloody, and it getting tainted by that, mixed with a bit of racist justification ("It's not about black people and their culture. It's about crime!").

Comment: Com certeza, @FuzzyBoots Sou capoeira tambem. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After following the link that @dmckee provided to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37881/name-of-short-sci-fi-story-involving-a-musician-who-is-punished-for-listening-to), I did a bit of googling, and found the story in question there - and it turns out that the story I was thinking of is, in fact, “Unaccompanied Sonata”, by Orson Scott Card. While it probably shouldn’t be, the [text of the story](https://www.sindark.com/LaTeX/unaccompanied-sonata.pdf) can be found on-line.

The few details I recalled above were a little off; the sequence of punishments was reversed, and it wasn't *generally* illegal to create new music, it was illegal *for the protagonist*, for reasons that might well be considered spoilers.

Comment: Cool. Congrats on finding it.

Comment: FWIW, I remember reading an abridged version, which stops with him being cast out without the further punishments, merely no longer someone whose music was being promoted, possibly from a kid's anthology.